# How to override a snippet in SublimeText 2/3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I would like to override a installed package's snippet with my own snippet. For example LatexTools package provides following snippet.

```
 \section{section name} % (fold)
 \label{sec:section_name}

% section section_name (end)
```

I would like to override it with following snippet.

```
 \section{section name} % (fold)
 \label{section-section_name}

% section section_name (end)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer. You can use this to navigate to the snippet you want. In ST3, it'll place the file in the proper location to override any installed packages.

Comment: Once extracted, the snippets can be found at `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` in (Ubuntu) Linux.

Comment: @Ralph using the plugin will open the correct file if you don't want to navigate to it. Of course, you are correct in where it will extract the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your modified snippet in:

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/LaTeX/`

Sublime Text should pick it up and override the default package snippet.

The path above is correct for Sublime Text version 3. It might be different is you're using on older version.